# Illegal offset type - Laravel 5.3 - ConnectionFactory.php - Every Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, php-7, laravel-backpack

First sorry for bad english, not native.

I'v an Laravel 5.3 App running on XAMPP, windows 7 machine.

Everything was working great, and i don't have made any impact changes on code, it just happened.

Everytime my app trys to build the connection with mysql this error is shown:

```
FatalThrowableError in ConnectionFactory.php line 237:
Illegal offset type
in ConnectionFactory.php line 237
ConnectionFactory->createConnector(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '3306', 'database' => 'megaboff', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => true, 'engine' => null, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 126
at ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 965
at Connection->getPdo() in Connection.php line 986
at Connection->getReadPdo() in Connection.php line 423
at Connection->getPdoForSelect(true) in Connection.php line 333
```

**I can use tinker to access my app and data in the database. It only don't work in browser.**

Any query to the database via browser this same error occurs. I did not change database config or env file. Here is the array:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'megaboff'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I would likely provide you more info as you seem it's needed, because now i don't have a clue why this is happening.

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: Are you using php artisan serve to run your app? If yes, restart php artisan serve. It should be restarted to reflect the changes in env file

Comment: i'm not using php artisan serve to run app. I'v xampp configured with vhosts. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  the command "php artisan config:cache" or "php artisan config:clear".
Can try too set your database configuration in the file .env.

Comment: @PedroX Have you tried leaving only the .env variables in your database.php configuration?
Type like this: env ('DB_HOST'), env ('DB_DATABASE') ...
And just set values in .env

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried two solutions but i'm not sure wich one worked:

- First i did a "php artisan config:clear" as suggested by Paulo Costa because yesterday i did the config:cache, but the problem was still here.
- Secondly i did a restart of WAMP (as suggested Roy Trenneman ;) ) and it worked.

So i'm not sure if both helped of just the restart.

Bonus :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UT8RkSmN4k